# React styled component specificity issue for modal calling custom styled modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-selectors, styled-components

I am working with styled component in React. I want to style a modal with the following style inside my component,

```
const StyledModal = styled(Modal)`
.modal-container-header {
    display: none;
}
.modal-container-footer {
    display: none ;
    
}
.modal-container-close {
    display: none;
}
```

`;

That is, I want to omit the global footer, header for my custom modal. It is working fine for one case but not working for another.

Here is the entire component,

```
interface LoaderInterface {
    loading: boolean;
    loadingText?: string;
}

const StyledModal = styled(Modal)`
   .modal-container-header {
        display: none;
    }
    .modal-container-footer {
        display: none ;
      
    }
    .modal-container-close {
        display: none;
    }
`;
const Loader: FC<LoaderInterface> = ({ loading, loadingText }) => {
    console.log("this modal is working");
    return (
        <StyledModal onClose={() => loading === false} open={loading}>
            <div>
                <Loading size="large" />
                <Heading type="h4">{loadingText}</Heading>
            </div>
        </StyledModal>
    );
};

export default Loader;
```

1. It is working when a general React functional component is calling the custom styled modal
2. but it is not working when a modal calling this custom modal. When the modal is triggering the custom modal then the style of the calling modal is getting effected. But I closed the calling modal before calling this custom modal.

In DEV tool I'm always seeing, for example, for footer,

```
.hPyTDi modal-container-footer {
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
padding: 16px 24px;
text-align: right;
}
```

That is the global style. Not my custom style. when I apply `display: none` inside the above code in the dev tool obviously it is working.

But this issue doesn't persist when my custom modal is called by a React functional component. Only this issue appears when a modal (which is also a React component) calls this custom modal.

I also tried '&' to increase specificity but it doesn't work.

I did,

```
&.modal-container-footer {
display: none; 
}
```

It doesn't work. If I move the custom modal style in a global place it works. But I don't want that as then this is applied for all modal where I want the header/footer to be visible.

Really struggling with this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into so many issues with the way Styled Components selectors, and come to realise that it's always 'safer' to pass props into them. This is because of the way SC dynamically assigns class names. Might this help?

```js
const StyledModal = styled(Modal)`
  ${ ({ hidden }) => hidden && `
    .modal-container-header, .modal-container-footer, .modal-container-close {
        display: none;
    }
  `}
`;

const Example = () => (
  <StyledModal hidden={()=>someFunction} />
)
```

For TypeScript, the syntax is similar:

```js
const StyledModal = styled.div<{hidden: boolean}>(...)
```

Comment: yes I am trying to close the loading modal with this. and that is working fine. just the style around the loading modal is not working. The functionality is working fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just about to update my answer to reflect.

Comment: thanks but it didnt work.the modal doesn't allow an extra prop hidden.typescript is throwing error..I tried to apply the same logic of property passing using existing property such as "open" such as .modal-container-header {
        display: ${(props: any) => (props.open ? "none" : "block")};
    } but it doesn't work

Comment: Amended answer for TypeScript